# "Value does not fall within the expected range." After adding a column in a existing list

Tags: error, list-definition

I updated a list of mine by adding a column.
After this update I receive the following error "Value does not fall within the expected range" when I try to get the data in the colum.

This is the code that I use to get the data:

```
        private static DateTime GetModified(SPListItem item)
    {
        var field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("LastRevision");

        if (!field.Hidden && item.Fields.ContainsFieldWithStaticName(field.StaticName) 
            && item.GetFormattedValue(field.InternalName) != null)
        {
            return (DateTime)item[field.Id];
        }

        return DateTime.Parse(item["StartDate"].ToString());
    }
```

I want show to you what happen with the Convert.ToDateTime too:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try with this code:

```
    private static DateTime GetModified(SPListItem item)
    {
        var properties = item.Properties;
        const string mycustomField = "LastRevision";
        var startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item["StartDate"].ToString());

        if (!properties.ContainsKey(mycustomField))
            return startDate;

        string lastRevision = properties[mycustomField].ToString();
        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(lastRevision, out dt))
            return dt;

        return startDate;
    }
```

if you use an item from a library you can get the metadata info by the properties of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting a null value in your date field, add some error checking on your parser... (Or use Convert.ToDateTime(string) which adds it for you)

DateTime.Parse only contains:

```
// Reflected code
internal static DateTime Parse(string s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
{
    if (!DateTimeParse.TryParse(s, dtfi, styles, ref result1))
    {
        throw DateTimeParse.GetDateTimeParseException(ref result1);
    }
        return result1.parsedDate;
    }
}
```

So if you try and parse the time data yourself by calling DateTimeParse.TryParse, I would then set the value to:

```
new DateTime((long) 0);
```

But as I said Convert.ToDateTime(string) handles this check for you.

[UPDATE]

To get the value of a field properly as a type:

```
DateTime fldModified = (DateTime)item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("CustomDateField");
```

Try that, I just tested on mine works fine.

Comment: it is not null the value inside but the system doesn't find the column!

Comment: @Gaetanu In that case you must be using the wrong internal name for the column. Edit the field and check the internal name for LastRevision.

Comment: it's correct; I got it by powershell

Comment: @Gaetanu there must be a reason why the field isn't being found. But surely your LastRevision column is no different to Modified? Try checking the list with SharePoint Manager, and having a look at the field in detail. http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438

Comment: I checked with SPM too and the name is correct. Yes, the mean of column is the same as Modified but the client wants this column too. I know is crazy.

Comment: I try to get the value from the column by the ID too

Comment: I added a picture that show to you what happens

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, okay check my answer.

Comment: Excuse me Hugh, maybe what I wrote don't make sense. My column is not "Modified" but it is a custom column that I added after a list update. The name of this column is LastRevision. It's a DATE column.

Comment: I know I was editing it from my test and saved to take a look, look again. Tested on custom field and modified.

Comment: Excuse me @Gaetanu, is it an item in a list or in a library? Did you try to use the Properties property?

Comment: no, I have not use it